# Why can't I accept an answer yet?

Tags: support, accepted-answer

I tried to accept an answer on [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/804234/what-does-expf-mean), and a message popped up saying "you may accept an answer in 12 minutes". Why is this the case?

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50697/time-limit-on-accepting-an-answer

Comment: Oh, thanks. That explains it.

Answer (score 3):

So as to remove this question from the unanswered list, I'll quote Aarobot from [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50697/time-limit-on-accepting-an-answer):

> It's actually 15 minutes as far as I know.  It started here:
>
> [Discourage questions being marked as answered within an hour or so of being posted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38090/discourage-questions-being-marked-as-answered-within-an-hour-or-so-of-being-poste)
>
> The rationale is that if people are accepting answers within minutes or even seconds (no joke), they haven't even had time to properly evaluate or test the answer.  The community felt (and I agreed) that some users were just accepting the first answer that was submitted even if it was wrong or sub-par.
>
> 15 minutes was decided on as the minimum amount of time it would take to receive a healthy number of submissions and actually read/test/think about the answers provided.